# How can I test the validations of a model if I use backbone validation

Tags: javascript, testing, backbone.js, backbone.validation.js

I have a backbone model

```
var MyModel= Backbone.Model.extend({
   validation: function () 
      var validate= { 
           name: {
               required: true,
           },
      };

      return validate;

   },
});
```

I use sinon, mocha and chai for test. When I call `model.validate()` in the test it tells me that the function does not exist, how can I check that the validation works?

Answer (score 1):

It seems you should do the following for validation plugin to work:

```
_.extend(Backbone.Model.prototype, Backbone.Validation.mixin);
```